# Output from loop not accepted by typewrite showing int object is not iterable

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey
import time 
time.sleep(1.5)    



for x in range(1,5):
  typewrite(x)
  hotkey('enter')
```

Using pyautogui trying simulate keyboard printing the number from loop

Comment: In some cases, these errors are tricky to track down because they originate in a long chain of code. In this case, I'm not sure what was obscure about this error message based on your code. Please become familiar with googling error messages and attempting to fix the problem yourself before posting questions.

Comment: Tried that didn't find any working answer

Answer (score 0):

Guessing `typewrite(x)` under the hood does some looping over the input, and you are providing it an `int`. You could try converting it to some sort of iterable and see if it fixes your problem: `typewrite([x])`

Comment: Worked with this 

 y = str(x)
 typewrite(y)

Answer (score 0):

Worked with this

```
y = str(x)
typewrite(y)
```